# get the index with value using arrayobject and store in array list

Tags: android, arraylist, arrays

```
  [  {
        "question_id": 13,
        "creation_date": 10,
        "name": " certain degrees",
        "tags": [
            "android",
            "sensor"
        ],
.....
...}

]
```

Here is the api I want to get the tags array ,the tag array contains only index and value,i want to get the array using array object and finally store in array list, i have tried but fail to get the error has been occured.

```
02-20 15:45:37.323: I/System.out(1165): org.json.JSONException: Value android at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

could anybody help me to solve this problem.

```
tagarray = questionobj.getJSONArray("tags");


        for(int j=0;j<tagarray.length();j++){



//tagobject = tagarray.getJSONObject(j);//..if i comment this line the full array list is displaying but i need for each question allocated tags to display..am i clear.. 
            //if(tagobject!=null){
            tagname.add(tagarray.getString(j));
            ///tagname.add(0, null);
            //} 
        }
```

Comment: just comment `tagobject = tagarray.getJSONObject(j);` line because u are getting only values inside JSONArray

Comment: why the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974878/get-the-array-index-with-value-using-arrayobject-and-store-in-array-list) question again?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i will do so..the answer wat i want i am not getting that

Comment: @R.J hope anybody can help me out thats why

Comment: people will reply to your post there. Posting same questions can only create duplicates here, and you may yourself lose track of it.

Comment: Hi can give ur api i will resolve this

Answer (score 0):

your json format is not correct
try like that;

```
{"question":
{"question_id": "13", 
 "name": "certain degrees", 
 "tags": [{"android":"N", "sensor":"Y"}]
 }}
```

You can use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, to be sure correction of your json data

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you try this code,

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "[  { \"question_id\": 13, \"creation_date\": 10, \"name\": \"certain degrees\", \"tags\": [ \"android\", \"sensor\" ] } ]";

        System.out.println(text);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);

        JSONObject jsonObjetc = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        JSONArray tagarray = jsonObjetc.getJSONArray("tags");

        System.out.println(tagarray);

        for(int j=0;j<tagarray.length();j++){
            System.out.println(tagarray.getString(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck, Aron

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String text = "[  { \"question_id\": 13, \"creation_date\": 10, \"name\": \"certain degrees\", \"tags\": [ \"android\", \"sensor\" ] } ]";
  try {
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray j_array = jarray.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getJSONArray("tags");

            for (int j = 0; j < j_array.length(); j++) {
                String str = j_array.getString(j);

                list.add(str);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

tagarray = questionobj.getJSONArray("tags");

```
    for(int j=0;j<tagarray.length();j++)
    {
        tagname.add(tagarray.getJSONObject(j).getString("android"));         
    }
```